# Scan XAP for Files

Tags: silverlight

i'm working on an Silverlight-Project, where i have some files in my XAP (in this case xml's) but the number of files can change and i don't even know the name of the files, but i want to read this files at runtime..
I know that due to Silverlight-Limitations it's not possible to scan a directory automatically, but maybe someone knows a workaround, **any** suggestion is appreciated.

(EDIT) 
Ok, i see my Question is not really clear so here some Background:
I'm working on an project that should support Modularity. A Module consists of a XAP and an XML-File, with some Meta-Information (like a Manifest in OSGI). Different developers should be able to build there Module and "deploy" it by putting there XML-Description in the XAP of the Main-Assembly (so Isolated Storage doesn't work).
I could use an XML-File to "link" all the other XML-Files, but that seems like an redundant step to me.

thanks in advance
olli

Comment: Why don't you put the files in an IsolatedStorage so that you have some more control over the files?

Answer (score 1):

(Original Answer)
Change the Xap file's extension to *.zip and open it with your favourite zip-program, or even windows file explorer for that matter - you'll be able to extract/see what's inside.

(PS Regarding the XML files)
I'd recommend keeping the XML files server-side and download them like it's shown [here](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/loading_xml_sl2_pg1.htm)

This is the "manual" way to do it. If that answer is what you're looking for , mark this post as answer.

Regards

Comment: thanks maciek, but i think, i wasn't clear enough.. i want to do at runtime!

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this and suddenly I've recalled this question...

http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/12/28/silverlight-reading-from-a-file-contained-in-your-xap/

PS. If you are looking to support modularity then I'd strongly recommend the Prism library.

It supports modularity and permits usage of ModuleCatalogs in XAML (xml) format.